# What skills should I learn before going for a PhD in numerical analysis, numerical linear algebra and scientific computing?

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, career-development

I have two years in my hand after which I would be applying for graduate school most probably in the US. I already have a masters degree in pure mathematics and have very limited computer skills. For some reason, eventually I got interested in applied mathematics. So, now I am going for a second masters (which has not yet started because of the pandemic) in applied mathematics which is heavy on the above-mentioned topics. As of computer skills, I have started learning C++ but I don't know what else should I learn. It would be very helpful if someone can give a roadmap which would prepare me to finally embark for a PhD in one of these areas i.e., in and around numerical analysis. What math and computer science courses should I take? What software should I learn? Any general advice you would like to give is also welcome. Book recommendations would also be very helpful for me.

Thanks!

PS- Sorry for my bad English (not a native speaker).

Comment: I think it belongs to math educators community...

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Thank you. I didn't know about that community.

Comment: This may help to prepare. In general, after a year, students take a preliminary exam (in at least two programs I know) the exams cover 2 of the 4 following topics: Real Analysis, Complex Analysis, Algebra, Topology. The applied track students take classes in math modeling (which are almost trivial for Eng. students!) and Numerical Analysis (2 classes - being good at real analysis is useful - Programing skills are welcome, but in general people use Python, the "gifted" students work in UNIX systems). Serious computations are done in Cpp/C and it is not unusual for students to learn them alone.

Comment: @sake Nothing at the undergraduate level (maybe some numerical analysis at the honors undergrad level or first year student in Engineering). Real analysis contains measure theory, but left topological spaces out as there was a class on topology. Although we cover topics outside the book you can check the table of contents of Folland, Real Analysis (Wiley), Ch. 1 to 8.5 to get a better idea of the topics.

Comment: @Basco Thank you very much for the info.

Comment: Good call with C++. Other options are MATLAB (or the free version, Octave), which is very common in all of the applied math programs I've seen. Occasionally, Python is used as well.

You may want to start learning anything from the following list: numerical integration/differentiation/interpolation, roundoff error, catastrophic cancellation, ODE/PDE solvers (e.g. finite element, Runge-Kutte), etc. Definitely not necessary to learn it all, but it may help you decide what you want to research! My class used *Numerical Analysis* by Gautschi.

Comment: @saka You don't need to get a second masters. Apply to PhD programs in Applied Mathematics (with a focus on scientific computing and numerical analysis) and pass the preliminary/qualification exams. I would focus on learning MATLAB (there are a lot of free resources online), C/C++, and high performance computing. You can pick up some of these skills in graduate school. Taking a course in data structures would be helpful (or read the material on your own).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll list some books I like. When I recommend a book, I don't necessarily mean that you should read the whole thing. You can just focus on the parts that seem most interesting.

For numerical linear algebra, I recommend reading Trefethen's book (called [Numerical Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898713617)).

For general applied math background, I'm a fan of [Introduction to Applied Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961408804) as well as [Computational Science and Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961408812), both by Gilbert Strang.

[Burden and Faires](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305253663) is a standard undergrad numerical analysis book and is worth reading. [Bulirsch and Stoer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144193006X) is a classic numerical analysis textbook at the advanced undergrad / beginning graduate level.

For optimization, I'm a fan of [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe as well as [Numerical Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387303030) by Nocedal and Wright (in particular I like chapter 12, "Theory of Constrained Optimization").

These days you should probably learn about machine learning even if it's not your research area, just because so many other people are working on it (and it's easy to learn the basics). For machine learning I recommend reading: 1) [The Hundred-Page Machine Learning Book](http://themlbook.com/) by Burkov; 2) [Deep Learning with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python-second-edition) by Francois Chollet; 3) [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) by James et al.

For an introduction to the Bayesian approach to statistics, I like [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124058884) by Kruschke.